# How to understand what is the asymptotic error constant by the plot? (Newton method)

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

So my teacher asked me to find out the rate of convergence and the asymptotic constant for Newthons method based on this experiment's graphs. We were searching for a simple root in the first case, and for multiple root in the second case. I've compared the graphs with the graphs demoing different rates of convergence on wiki and concluded that it's quadratic in the first case and linear in the second. But can I actually tell anything about the asymptotic constant by just looking at a graph? Is there a way to calculate it? (Didn't find one on Google. ) Thanks for your time!

[for simple root][1] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwiPa.png

[for multiple root][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed2ha.png

Comment: "can I actually tell anything about the asymptotic constant by just looking at a graph?" Applied math people tend to give badly posed problems like that. But you are lucky. This one is not that bad. Here there are numbers in the axes.

Comment: The graphs tell you iterations vs error of the approximation. Assuming that [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence#Convergence_speed_for_iterative_methods) is the definition of rate of convergence that they want you to use, 'iterations' is the $k$ and 'error' is the value of the whole term $\log_{10}|x_k-L|$ (or who knows what base of logarithm). Note: I translated the names of the axes using OCR and Google translate. Maybe it is not the correct translation.

Comment: Let's start with the second graph. It looks like (I cringe saying that) the graph is a straight line that passes through the points $(20,-25)$ and $(50,-35)$. Therefore the line $-k/3-55/3$, or in other words $|x_k-L|=10^{-k/3-55/3}$. Putting this in the definition in the link we get that $|x_{k+1}-L|/|x_k-L|=10^{-1/3}$, which tells us that it converges linearly with rate $10^{-1/3}$ (given all the assumptions we had to make).